# Data table child rows works once per 2 updates

Tags: javascript

So I'm using Electron.js, datables.net plugin, and child rows.

When I am updating data in the table, child rows stop working until I update data once more, and so on. So child-rows works only once per two data updates. I tried to make a loop where code executes two times, but no success. I got data from Postgres database.

```
var table = window.$('#table_id').DataTable({
  data: data,
  select: "single",
  retrieve: true,
  columns: [{
      "className": 'details-control',
      "orderable": false,
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": '',
      "render": function() {
        return '<i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
      },
      width: "15px"
    },
    {"data": "fn"},
    {"data": "username"},
    {"data": "timestamp"},
    {"data": "filename"},
    {"data": "agent"},
    {"data": "job_type"},
    {"data": "progress"},
    {"data": "status"},
    {"data": "priority"},
  ],
  "order": [
    [1, 'asc']
  ]
});

myConsole.log("1")

window.$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
  var tr = window.$(this).closest('tr');
  var tdi = tr.find("i.fa");
  var row = table.row(tr);

  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
    tdi.first().removeClass('fa-minus-square');
    tdi.first().addClass('fa-plus-square');
  } else {
    // Open this row
    row.child(format(row.data())).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
    tdi.first().removeClass('fa-plus-square');
    tdi.first().addClass('fa-minus-square');
  }
});

window.$('#table_id').on("user-select", function(e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent) {
  if (window.$(cell.node()).hasClass("details-control")) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

function format(d) {
  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Path:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.path + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Message::</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.message + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
}

window.$('#table_id').DataTable().clear().draw();
window.$('#table_id').DataTable().rows.add(data); // Add new data
window.$('#table_id').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw(); // Redraw the DataTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, problem was, that each time when i update data and code is running once more, another event listener is created. Code just open and close child row when there is even number of listeners, you just cant see it by eye :) 
To fix this issue i added "**.off('click')**" in my code and now everything works as should.

```
  window.$('#table_id tbody').off('click').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
```